# Typo3 8 - realurl - how to display page id instead of full path slug

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have a fresh installation of Typo3 8.7, wanted to upgrade from 4.7. 
In both I have installed the RealURL extension for displaying a human readable url.
Problem is in 8.7 the resulted url contains the full path slug name, compared with the 4.7 installation where it display the page ID (the desired output).

New site page url (same page):
https://new87site/tickets/incident-and-service-request/service-view/incidents-and-sr-service-view/

Old site url:
https://old47site/2147/

Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you copy the `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php` from your old project?

Comment: If you mean ext_localconf.php, then no, it is signifficantly different from the new one. Cannot seem to find the fie you mention above....

Answer (score 1):

RealUrl has a configuration file. It is configured in the extension's settings (in TYPO3 v8 accessible via the extension manager). The default is `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`.
[image: extension config]

If that file does not exist and the option "automatic configuration" is active, it will regenerate the file.

I don't know the setting to use page IDs as slugs, but on the old system this setting should be in there.

You can make changes to the file or (recommended) use a hook (`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/realurl/class.tx_realurl_autoconfgen.php']['extensionConfiguration']['yourExt']`) to have your config merged with the auto-configuration.